# Authentication section

Tags: python, passwords

I'm trying to design a game where the user rolls a dice and gets points added to their score. However, it needs a way to store users, which it has in the form of an external file.

Can anyone help me in trying to write this section of code which checks if the username and password is in the external file? If not, it closes the program, preventing the user from playing. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
authen = str(input("Please enter a valid username and password: "))

if authen is not in (users.txt):

break
```

Comment: There are actually quite a few sub-questions here: how to get a username and password from input, how to open a file, how to check if the username and password pair are in the file...you might benefit from better scoping your question.

Comment: I just want to check if the username and password are the file. I've already opened the file:

Comment: file = open("users.txt", "r")

Comment: If your question is just "how to locate text in a file", then `text in file.read()` will be a boolean value, for some value of `text`, that should be sufficient. However, given your use-case, that will likely not be enough.